# PLSQL - falha no Nextval

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

O seguinte codigo:

Crie uma Trigger que efetua a criação de um registro de log toda vez que um produto for alterado.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CREATE_LOG
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON PRODUTO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO LOG VALUES (IDLOG.NEXTVAL,SYSDATE, 'Produto ' || 
cast(:NEW.IDPRODUTO as varchar(10)) || ' alterado' );
END;
```

Esta apresentando o seguinte erro :

Errors: TRIGGER CREATE_LOG
Line/Col: 3/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 3/25 PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Comment: Poste a definição da tabela `LOG`.

Comment: Olá, Poste o DDL(Create) da tabela e da Sequence para analisarmos melhor.

Comment: A sequence chamada não existe. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314

Comment: se outro usuário do banco executa a sequence, certifique-se também que deu permissão usando `grant`